Including data in an interpolation without adding them as nodes
I am writing data reduction software for mass spectrometry for degassing mineral samples and measuring the gas released. One of the things that my software does is to take measurements of the blank level over the time of the sequence and to interpolate that blank level to the time of the samples to calculate a unique blank correction for each sample.
In addition to 'real' blanks, we also have 're-extracts': these are secondary analyses on each sample to ensure that all the gas was released during the first analysis. Assuming that these are at blank level (within 2$\sigma$ of the mean of the real blanks), these can be used as additional pseudo-blanks.
I want to include these 're-extract' data in the cubic interpolation without adding them as interpolation nodes. This is because

Re-extracts are dense (there are a ton of them) relative to real blanks
We are measuring blank level, which involves a lot of noise

These factors mean that when I try to add the re-extracts alongside the true blanks as interpolation nodes, it breaks the fitting routine and everything goes to zero.
My question is: how can I include these data in a cubic interpolation to influence the fit without actually adding them as interpolation nodes? Surely, there is a way, but I don't know the proper terminology.
I could use simple weighting but each blank measurement and re-extract also has an error associated with it which I am currently using to weight the interpolation, I'm not sure how I would combine the errors with some arbitrary weights.
